# How can i change my navbar to multiple icons when in mobile view in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have 4 links in my `navbar` and i want to bring all 4 links from `navbar` to the center of the screen when re sizing the window to the smallest (mobile display). How can i do that in Bootstrap?

Comment: Check my code at www.tmawto.com, resize to small size, i think thats what you are looking for. Feel free to adapt code.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `<li> </li>` elements different column lengths with classes. For example, indicating that when extra small (mobile), `<li class="col-xs-12">link</li>` will tell the link to take up the whole length of the navbar when the screen size is that of an "xs" which is usually mobile. To make this different for other screen sizes, just add a different column count to the class argument, for example: `<li class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"></li>` will take up the whole navbar when screen sizes match extra small and small but from anything medium and above, it will only take 3 columns.